# In Tkinter is there any way to Zoom in/out on the whole of the GUI content?

Tags: python, tkinter

Looking for similar functionality that a browser has? (ctrl:shift:+ for example)

I tried:
`root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', new_scale)` but it didn't change anything.

Any suggestions greatly welcomed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Tkinter is there any way to Zoom in/out on the whole of the GUI content?

No, there is no way to do what you want. There is a way to scale items on a canvas, and you can scale fonts (and thus, widgets that depend on the size of a font) but you can't the UI as a whole.